# Extending java.util.Random.nextInt(int) into nextLong(long)

Tags: java, random

In `java.util.Random` the Oracle implementation of `nextInt(int)` is as follows:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

I have a need to do the same thing for `long`s, but this is not included as part of the class signature. So I extended the class to add this behavior. Here's my solution, and even though I'm pretty sure I have it right, bit-twiddling can subtly fluster even the best of devs!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LongRandom extends Random {

    public long nextLong(long n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");    

        if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
            return nextLong() & (n - 1); // only take the bottom bits

        long bits, val;
        do {
            bits = nextLong() & 0x7FFFFFFFL; // make nextLong non-negative
            val = bits % n;
        } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
        return val;

    }
}
```

Have I introduced a subtle bug? Are there improvements to make? What might I need to watch out for?

Comment: You can find some alternatives on SO.

Comment: Unlike Microsoft, Sun got that code right. Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with n>2^32 and your code will fail. `0x7FFFFFFFL` reduces your code to `int`, breaking your extension to `long`. You need to use the maximal value of `long` not `int` in your mask. i.e. `7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test, It's that simple.
I've tested your code on C#, minus the `& 0x7FFFFFFFL; // make nextLong non-negative`

(I didn't need that, C# rands are positive)

The results look well distributed on [0,N-1].
So I think code is fine, except for the part I did not test.

Comment: The problem with testing is that it’s categorically impossible to prove correctness through it. Your test in particular fails to find failing cases which another answer has found.

Comment: That's nonsense. Did you *read* my post? You don't test to 'prove correctness', that's for the academics. You test to find faults.

Comment: I actually think my previous comment was premature. But your “that’s for academics” dismissal is ridiculous.

Comment: So style and phrasing aside, we're on accord on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar method in [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/): [`RandomDataGenerator.nextLong(long lower, long upper)`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html#nextLong%28long,%20long%29).

See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)